# Get last item in select

Tags: asp-classic

How do you get the last item in a select HTML element in ASP?

```
<select id="AggregationLevel" name="AggregationLevel" onchange="javascript:SF(true)">


                                <option  value="1">Monthly</option>

                                <option  value="2">Weekly</option>

                                <option  selected='selected'  value="3">Daily</option>


                </select>
```

Comment: You got it solved by now? From your comments on the answer it didn't look like that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = document.getElementById("AggregationLevel").options.length;
var j = document.getElementById("AggregationLevel").selectedIndex;
alert(document.getElementById("AggregationLevel").options[i-1].value); // last item
alert(document.getElementById("AggregationLevel").options[j].value); // selected item, if this is what you're  interested in
```

Comment: Thanks...how would I call this from within some ASP code?  I am quite unfamiliar with Classic ASP and having to urgently fix some legacy code.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you're asking. Do you want to read the value of last <option> inside "server side" code? If so, classic ASP does not work like ASP.NET. You must hook some code inside the server side loop that generates the select list box.

Comment: You would have to post the option selected to either a new page or the current page. Then you recive the value from a Request.Form() operation. If you have anykind of javascript involved you could ofcourse do a asynchrone call to a webservice or something to avoid reloading the page.

Comment: Once the select has been populated, I want to read the last element in it.

Comment: @user517406 as i wrote above, this needs to be done thru either a post or a asynchrone select. They way i would do it is to force a submit via JavaScript onChange. The Onchange would go back to the same page and and collect the values needed from the form. You could also add the last element as a querystring to the post and get it on the reload by using request.querystring()

Comment: @user517406 are you sure you need to get the last element after the page is loaded? If you could explain a bit more in detail what your trying to accomplish perhaps I or someone else can figure out a way to get past the reload/asynch call.

Comment: @Marthin and @user517406: As far as I think, the _last item in a select HTML_ remains the same irrespective of what the user chooses from the list. So ideally you should do it one the server side, may be put a hook inside the loop that generates the select list.

Comment: Do you want the selected item or the last physical item? they could be different.